# wso2 key management functionality

Tags: wso2

Some of the current key management functionality (in Carbon 4.0.3) is listed below:

- User can use Carbon to add (upload) a keystore (a single private key must be present in the keystore)
- User can use Carbon to add (upload) certificates to an existing keystore
- User can use Carbon to view private and public key certificates in an existing keystore
- User can use Carbon to delete public key certificates in an existing keystore

Using this model, users that are uploading new keystores will have access to the private keys which should be avoided in higher security environments.

For that reason, I need to support a few additional use cases:

- User can use Carbon to delete the private key in a keystore
- User can use Carbon to create the private key in a keystore (specifying the x509 fields)
- User can use Carbon to create a new keystore
- Keystores that have been created or modifier are copied to cluster member nodes (this may already be supported?)
- User can use Carbon to create and download a certificate signing request for the private key (**EDIT: 1st July**)

I would also like to support the following use case:

- Carbon keystore can contain multiple private key entries

I have a feeling that the use case above may break other functionality in Carbon that expects just one private key per keystore?

I would be happy to develop this functionality, but would prefer the functionality to be useful for others so it could be contributed back.

Are these use cases useful for the WSO2 community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a few positive responses to the proposal, so I have created a JIRA feature request: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14173